# populate object properties using lambda expression in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, lambda

**Newbie Alert!** I feel silly asking this question but I need someone to teach me the correct syntax.

I have code that looks like this:

```
let thing: INewThing;
thing.personId = another.personId;
thing.address = another.work.address;
thing.greades = another.subjectInfo.grades;
thing.isCurrent = another.student.isCurrent;
```

I know it can be written cleaner.  I want to use a lamda expression, something like this:

```
let thing: INewThing => {
    personId = another.personId,
    address = another.work.address,
    grades = another.subjectInfo.grades,
    isCurrent = another.student.isCurrent
} as IThingUpdate;
```

I have looked and looked for an example. I have yet to find one that works for me. It's just syntax but no matter what I try it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just looking to create a new object, which is a pretty different thing from a "lambda" (function). Just declare the object. You don't need a function.

```
const thing = {
  personId: another.personId,
  address: another.work.address,
  // use the correct spelling below - no 'greades'
  grades: another.subjectInfo.grades,
  isCurrent: another.student.isCurrent,
};
```

If the `another` is typed properly, that should be sufficient.

If the `another` object had more properties using the same path, another option would be to destructure those properties out, then declare the object with shorthand, eg:

```
const originalObj = { prop: 'val', nested: { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', unwanted: 'unwanted' } };
const { foo, bar } = originalObj.nested;
const thing = { foo, bar };
```

Destructuring like this, without putting the values into differently-named properties, helps reduce typos - if a property starts out, for example, as `someLongPropertyName`, putting it into a standalone identifier `someLongPropertyName` and then constructing an object with shorthand syntax ensures that the new object also has the exact property name `someLongPropertyName` (and not, for example, `someLongPRopertyName` - which isn't that uncommon of a mistake when using the more traditional object declaration format).

But since all the paths in your `another` object are different, this approach wouldn't work well in this particular situation.